# Find shortest path on three.js mesh?

Tags: three.js, graph-algorithm

I'd like to create an app using three.js where a user can paint polygons (well, actually, face loops) on a mesh.

The user would pick faces A and B using their mouse and the raycaster, and then I want to find all of the faces along the shortest path between A and B and color them.

Are there any built in utilities that will assist with this, or any examples to use?

I haven't found any so unless you can direct me to something I will implement a shortest path algorithm myself... I guess I have to start with creating an adjacency list from the threejs geometry.

Comment: Using [`THREE.Geometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry), you can access the [`faces` property](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry.faces), which is a list of all faces in the geometry. [`THREE.BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry) doesn't have this convenience, but is more efficient, if that's a concern of yours. Still you know that every three values in the `position` attribute are a vertex. These are usually referenced by the `index` property, and every three indices compose a face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any three.js examples or extensions that did shortest path or tree search, so I just [wrote it myself](https://github.com/foobarbecue/threejs-shortest-path). Running [here](https://foobarbecue.github.io/threejs-shortest-path/).